# Won't update UILabel from Parse data in swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uilabel

I am trying to update my UILabel to a String from my Parse database.
My problem is the label will not update my firstnameLabel when I first sign in. But it WILL update, when i sign in (nothing happens), push the stop button in Xcode and then launch it again (still logged in) and then it updates the label.
How can I do this faster??

Here is my code:

```
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
if currentUser != nil {


    var query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(currentUser.objectId) {
        (bruger: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil && bruger != nil {
            var firstName: String = bruger["firstname"] as String
            self.usernameLabel.text = firstName
        } else {
            println("Error")
        }
    }


} else {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: self)
}
```

Hope you can help me!

Comment: Try to update the UILabel in MainQueue

Comment: I tried something like depatch_get_main_queue, but it didn't work anyway. How would you implement it in the code?

Comment: I notice that you have various spellings of "firstName" - they should all match.  If your Parse class has "firstName" then you need to use that throughout.

Comment: In the Parse database, it is called "firstname", but the variable i am making is called firstName which is calling the value from the Parse database "firstname"

Comment: As I am saying before the code, it IS working, it is just not working as fast as it should, and you should not have to close and open the app again for it to display the firstname of the person who logged in :-)

Comment: Can't you just use currentUser[@"firstname"] without needing the query?

Comment: I hope I would, but if I write currentUser["firstname"] instead of the whole query part, I get the error "Expression resolves to an unused l-value (or I-value, it's hard to tell)"

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to load the user object again by the id, try just doing a fetch instead.

```
[currentUser fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock: ... ];
```

By trying to load the object, you might be getting a cached version.

Comment: Okay I used your code like this:
currentUser.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock({ (bruger: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    var firstName: String = bruger["firstname"] as String
                    self.usernameLabel.text = firstName
                })

And it DOES show the data in the UILabel quicker than before (before it showed the placeholder text of the UILabel first, then the real data), but it still doesn't update the label write away. I need to stop the app and start it again before it does :-(

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that it could be because of the fact that the could was put inside the ViewDidLoad. I tried to put it outside of that and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you put it in the ViewDidLoad method. You should put it in the ViewWillAppear method instead. Here's an example.

1) ViewDidLoad - Whenever I'm adding controls to a view that should appear together with the view, right away, I put it in the ViewDidLoad method. Basically this method is called whenever the view was loaded into memory. So for example, if my view is a form with 3 labels, I would add the labels here; the view will never exist without those forms.

2) ViewWillAppear: I use ViewWillAppear usually just to update the data on the form. So, for the example above, I would use this to actually load the data from my domain into the form. Creation of UIViews is fairly expensive, and you should avoid as much as possible doing that on the ViewWillAppear method, becuase when this gets called, it means that the iPhone is already ready to show the UIView to the user, and anything heavy you do here will impact performance in a very visible manner (like animations being delayed, etc).

3) ViewDidAppear: Finally, I use the ViewDidAppear to start off new threads to things that would take a long time to execute, like for example doing a webservice call to get extra data for the form above.The good thing is that because the view already exists and is being displayed to the user, you can show a nice "Waiting" message to the user while you get the data.